# WYPopoverController: how to pass an image to a popover

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, uicollectionview

I'm displaying articles in a UICollectionView, with a button to open a WYPopoverController where the user can zoom in the image.

To avoid downloading the image twice, I'm trying to pass the image from the UICollectionView to the popover, but it is not working:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    LOArcticlesCustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[articlesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"photoUrl"]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"simboloLakari29.png"]];


    index= indexPath.row;

    self.imageArticle = cell.imageView.image;
    self.imageUrl = [NSString stringWithString:[[articlesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"photoUrl"]];
    cell.lblMake.text = [NSString stringWithString:[[articlesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"marca"]];
    cell.lblMake.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.lblModel.text = [NSString stringWithString:[[articlesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"modelo"]];
    cell.lblModel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.lblPrice.text = [NSString stringWithString:[[articlesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"precio"]];
    cell.lblOrder.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld de %ld", (unsigned long)indexPath.row+1, (unsigned long)articlesArray.count];

    //button magnify position
    CGFloat screenHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
    if (screenHeight == 568) {
        cell.magnify.frame = CGRectMake(145.0, 418.0, 30.0, 30.0);
        cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 45.0, 260.0, 260.0);
    }

    return cell;
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"biggerPicture"])
    {

        WYStoryboardPopoverSegue* popoverSegue = (WYStoryboardPopoverSegue*)segue;

        LOBiggerPictureViewController* destinationViewController = (LOBiggerPictureViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;


        destinationViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 320);
        destinationViewController.imageDownloaded = self.imageArticle;


        popoverController = [popoverSegue popoverControllerWithSender:sender permittedArrowDirections:WYPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
        popoverController.delegate = self;
        WYPopoverBackgroundView* appearance = [WYPopoverBackgroundView appearance];
        [appearance setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

       UIColor* popColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:126/255.0 green:34/255.0 blue:110/255.0 alpha:1.0];


        WYPopoverBackgroundView* popoverAppearance = [WYPopoverBackgroundView appearance];

        [popoverAppearance setOuterCornerRadius:4];
        [popoverAppearance setOuterShadowBlurRadius:1];
        [popoverAppearance setOuterShadowColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
        [popoverAppearance setOuterShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1, 1)];

        [popoverAppearance setGlossShadowColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        [popoverAppearance setGlossShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1, 1)];

        [popoverAppearance setBorderWidth:8];
        [popoverAppearance setArrowHeight:10];
        [popoverAppearance setArrowBase:20];

        [popoverAppearance setInnerCornerRadius:4];
        [popoverAppearance setInnerShadowBlurRadius:0];
        [popoverAppearance setInnerShadowColor:[UIColor darkTextColor]];
        [popoverAppearance setInnerShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1, 1)];

        [popoverAppearance setFillTopColor:popColor];
        [popoverAppearance setFillBottomColor:popColor];
        [popoverAppearance setOuterStrokeColor:popColor];
        [popoverAppearance setInnerStrokeColor:popColor];
        UINavigationBar* navBarInPopoverAppearance = [UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationController class], [WYPopoverController class], nil];
        [navBarInPopoverAppearance setTitleTextAttributes: @{
                                                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName  : [UIColor clearColor],
                                                             NSShadowAttributeName : [UIColor lightGrayColor],
                                                             NSShadowAttributeName : [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)]}];
    }

}
```

And in the popover:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

      [self.imageView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:imageDownloaded waitUntilDone:YES];

    [self.imageView sizeToFit];
    self.scrollView.contentSize =self.image.size;
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale   =  1.0;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale    = 3.0;

}
```

A NSLog shows a null object. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Popovers in storyboard are sort of deprecated in Xcode 6. The first thing you should check is your segue to your popover and see if the "segue" drop down says "Popover" or "Present as Popover". I believe in "Popover" a few things have stopped working correctly on iOS8.

If your app is capable, simply changing it to "Present as Popover" may fix this issue. If you don't have that option, checking the "Use size classes" box in the "File Inspector" portion of storyboard (first tab) should enable the new popovers.

Comment: The problem appeared on Xcode 5.1 The popover is displayed but the image won't appear. Need to take your approach and make some tests.

Comment: If it's Xcode 5 then you're right, my answer is not really a solution. I just encountered a few similar problems with my storyboard popovers after upgrading Xcode. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the image in the *viewWillAppear* instead of the *viewDidLoad*.  I think the variable hasn't yet been set by the *prepareforSegue* at that point.